# constructing on the fly recursive structure with vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to know why the following code is wrong to the compiler :

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    vector<foo> b;
};

int main() {
    foo c = foo{1, vector<foo>{1, vector<foo>{1}}};
}
```

whereas it compiles with this one:

```
foo c = foo{1, vector<foo>{1}};
```

Is that because this kind of nested structure construction is not supported or I am doing it all wrong ?

Comment: `vector<foo>` doesn't have a two-parameter constructor taking an `int` and a `vector<foo>`. If you meant to construct a vector holding a single instance of `foo`, then this works: `foo c = foo{1, vector<foo>{{1, vector<foo>{1}}}};`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Use [boost recursive wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/doc/html/class.boost.recursive_wrapper.html):

```
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
struct foo;
struct foo {
    int a;
    vector<boost::recursive_wrapper<foo>> b;
};
```

If you don't want to use boost or roll your own wrapper,
consider using a pointer internally.

Comment: Why do you need the forward declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You did small mistake, of course it works but you need to use correct `vector` constructor.

This creates vector of foo's with 1 object inside (initialized with automatically generated default constructor):

```
auto v = vector<foo>{1u};
```

You can list objects, that you create explicitly:

```
auto x = foo{3, vector<foo>{ foo{1, vector<foo>{1u}},
                             foo{2, vector<foo>{1u}} }};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually illegal to pass an incomplete type to `std::vector`.  There really isn't a good reason why it is illegal, but the standard says so.

Your code will compile and work if you type:

```
foo c = foo{1, vector<foo>{{1, vector<foo>{1}}}};
```

notice the extra set of `{}`.  But it won't be standards compliant, at least with C++11.

There are a few types, like `std::unique_ptr`.  You can do a `vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>` legally.

```
foo c = {1, {std::make_unique<Foo>( 1 )}};
```

Note, however, that `make_unique` doesn't support `{}` based construction very well within it.  Using a move ctor works:

```
foo c = {1, {std::make_unique<Foo>( Foo{1, {}} )}};
```